# How can \externalfigure[] load a filename based on section markings?

Tags: graphics, sectioning, context

I'm working on a somewhat complex layout that uses ConTeXt's layers to lay out headers and footers with text and border graphics. I am trying to reuse my layer definitions by making them responsive to the chapter markings.

I currently have the markings working fine in the running head text. That's no problem. What I'm running into is that I can't figure out how to select the border graphics based on the markings.

Simply, I want to be able to use `\getmarking[MyMark]` as part of the name of an external graphic, to automatically adapt the layer border graphics to each section.

This MWE is very minimal, with nothing about layers or headers/footers, just my attempts to use a marking to set the graphic filename at all. It becomes a MnWE (minimal non-working example) when any of the `\externalfigure` lines are uncommented:

```
\definemarking[MyMark]

\starttext

\marking[MyMark]{The Title}

Marking: \getmarking[MyMark][current]

% (1) this fails to run
% Graphic: \externalfigure[\getmarking[MyMark][current]]

% (2) this also fails
% Graphic: \externalfigure[{\getmarking[MyMark][current]}]

% (3) also fails, of course, but is closer to what I want to accomplish
% Graphic: \externalfigure[headerfig-\getmarking[MyMark][current]-recto.pdf]

\stoptext
```

Is there a correct way to use the text inside `\getmarking` as the filename for `\externalfigure`? If I had that, I could easily work it into my existing setups.

I have investigated related topics on the ConTeXt mailing list and *have* located [a way to use variables to define the filename to load](https://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg86991.html). However, that doesn't solve my problem: trying to use a marking to define a variable causes the same errors. It would leave me still manually setting variables at the top of each section. Not intolerable, but still leaves me unable to leverage the markings that are already set, or using any of the marking logic.

My suspicion, based on those experiments, is that the problem is related to expansion. I don't know enough about handling expansion to even begin to investigate that idea though.

(If all else fails I can do something manual, either with variables or a set of macros per section or some kind of hardcoded `\doiftext` chain against each known section name, but I can't help thinking there *must* be some way to get the text out of the markings and into the filename used in my existing layer setups.)

Comment: Have you tried `\expanded{\externalfigure[...][..]}`?

Comment: @Aditya Yes, it fails with the familiar fatal error 256 on that line. I tried various combinations of \expanded, \safeexpanded, \unexpanded, just stabbing in the dark without knowing what I was doing, without any success.

Comment: You could also try `\fetchmark` and `\fetchmarking` which are expandable.

Comment: @Aditya Almost! It returns `{The Title}`, with the braces, and errors when fed to `\externalfigure`. However, putting it into a variable and then that variable into `\externalfigure` does work! (I tried that same indirect data flow with `\getmarking` and that still dies with a fatal error, so `\fetchmarking` is definitely helping somehow.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a tip from [Aditya](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/323/aditya) to try `\fetchmarking`, I figured out this method that compiles and delivers the expected functionality, but only when the output of `\fetchmarking` is “buffered” through a variable first:

```
\definemarking[MyMark]

\starttext

\marking[MyMark]{section-image}

Does not work as expected, but compiles:

\externalfigure[\expanded{\fetchmarking[MyMark][][current]}]

% This does not compile
% \externalfigure[\fetchmarking[MyMark][][current]]

Works! Not clear why though:

\setvariable{ThoseMarkings}{title}{\fetchmarking[MyMark][][current]}

\externalfigure[\getvariable{ThoseMarkings}{title}]

Also allows string concatenation to get final filename:

\externalfigure[prefix-\getvariable{ThoseMarkings}{title}-suffix]

\stoptext
```

This solves my problem!

Comment: The first variant works when you use `\expanded` on `\externalfigure` (`\expanded{\externalfigure[{\fetchmarking[MyMark][page][current]}]}`).